# accessing html variable in jsp code

Tags: jsp

I have this code:

```
<%@ include file="/WEB-INF/views/include.jsp" %>

<body>
    <div class=col1>
        <h1>Projects</h1>
        <p>Selecciona un proyecto de la lista</p>
        <h3>Projects</h3>
   <c:forEach items="${model.projects}" var="project">
      <a href="project_popup.htm" onclick=<% application.
                    setAttribute("project", project); %>>
        <c:out value="${project.getProject().getName()}"/><br></a>
      <c:out value="${project.getRol().getString()}"/><br>
      <c:out value="${project.getDateStart()}"/><br>
      <br><br>
    </c:forEach>

    </div>
</body>
```

line: `<a href="project_popup.htm" onclick=<% application.setAttribute("project", project); %>>`, fails because project cannot be resolved into a variable even if it's on the foreach loop...

does anyone knows how to access those variables?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you have get/set methods established for each field on an object you simply use the field name.

```
  <c:out value="${project.project.name}"/><br></a>
```

I'm a little suspicious as to why a `project` would have a `project` field. Are you sure you didn't want:

```
  <c:out value="${project.name}"/><br></a>
```

This piece of code won't fly however:

```
<a href="project_popup.htm" onclick=<% application.
                    setAttribute("project", project); %>>
```

You cannot trigger some server side event using the `onclick` attribute of an `a` tag.  The client cannot directly execute some code on the server, it needs to happen through a request.  Usually, `ajax` and a `servlet` is used to handle this type of scenario, although you could also send a full request to the server.

[Here is a simple example showing how to use servlets](http://www.mkyong.com/servlet/a-simple-servlet-example-write-deploy-run/)

Comment: the project var within a project var is fine, i will rename it in order to be more clear, but that works fine...

the problem with the other piece of code is the following:
i want to print a list of the projects the user is working at, and the user will be able to click any of the tittles of these projects to access further details. i have another jsp for the project.jsp single display, but i don't know how to pass the proper project variable to it